# How to parse file.dat by php

Tags: parsing

i want to parsing from file.dat
and this is the content from file.dat

```
!
interface gpon-onu_0/1/1:0
  ***name 141231-MEDIS ngasem***
  description $$$$146423109789-MEDIS ngasem
!

interface gpon-onu_0/1/1:1
  ***name 747192030-HERU SUJOKO***
  description $$$$kendal
  vport-mode gemport def-map-type 1:1
  tcont 2 name Voip allocid 258 profile UP-1M
  tcont 2 gap mode2
  tcont 3 name SPEEDY allocid 259 profile UP-768K
!
```

how if i want to get value from name in interface 0/1/1:0 and interface 0/1/1:1 by php?
please help me :))

Comment: Look in this link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6657191/php-parsing-a-dat-file

Comment: the code is not work for myweb
please help me to get some data from the file.dat

i want like it

interface : gpon-onu 0/1/1:0<br>
name : 141231-MEDIS ngasem<br>
<br>
interface : gpon-onu_0/1/1:1<br>
name : 747192030-HERU SUJOKO